# Give a box an ID, once clicked shows alert of that ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The idea is when the button is clicked it will generate as many boxes as there are clicks (ex: 20 clicks = 20 boxes on the page) However, I need it where when you click on the box an alert of a unique ID pops up. I'm not sure of how to assign each box a unique ID...

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>E02W03_Q2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="E03_Q2.css">
        <script src="E03_Q2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Box">
        </form>
        <div class="clrBox">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code:

```
.clrBox { 
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

The JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    var box = document.getElementByTagName("div");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    box.onclick = handelBoxClick;
}

function handleButtonClick(e) { 
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","clrBox");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body[0].appendChild(div);
}

function handelBoxClick(e){ <<This isnt quite finished yet since i'm not sure of how to assign each box a unique id...
    var div = document.getElementById("");
    alert();

}
```

Comment: `box.onclick = handelBoxClick;` should be `box.onclick = handleBoxClick;` Not really related to your problem, but something to bear in mind.

Comment: Are you open to use jQuery to handle it?

Comment: @Blaise jQuery cannot be used sadly.

Comment: Heh now that I look again I realize you misspelled it in the function declaration as well so it wouldn't actually matter (except for readability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

var i=0;
function handleButtonClick() { 
   i++;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","clrBox");
    div.setAttribute("id","box"+i);
    div.onclick=function(){handleBoxClick(div);}
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body[0].appendChild(div);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kBMeJ/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, this is what you need to do. In `handleButtonClick`:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("class","clrBox");
div.id = "some_id"; // probably something auto-generated, remember that it needs to be unique!
```

Pretty simple.

Comment: ahhh, yes this makes sense. How exactly would you auto-generate a string value? Or would something like a global variable which would be added +1 each time work?

Comment: A global variable would work. Or you could do something like this: `div.id = 'box_' + document.getElementsByClassName("clrBox").length;`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var count = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
div.id = 'b' + (count + 1);
```

Comment: `div.id = 'b' + (count++)`

Comment: @Orlando, I agree. You don't know if `count++` means before or after `'b' + ...`. It is very susceptible to bugs.

Comment: @Orlando It doesn't do the same thing, and will always generate the same id

Comment: (I'm assuming `count` is only taken from the number of divs once, not on every click; it it's on every click, okay - and actually, the `+1` isn't even necessary)

Comment: oh yeah totally, you are right... that should be `count = count + 1`.. but always avoid the increment operator (`++`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the length property of the container to assign an incremented `id` to each div.

```
function handleButtonClick(e) { 
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName("clrBox")[0];
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    // Increment id
    div.id = "box-" + container.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pA9QG/

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

run this within your init handler (jsFiddle executes it onLoad):
http://jsfiddle.net/8sWgF/

```
document.getElementById("addButton").onclick = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    var addBox = function() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class","clrBox");
        div.id = "clrBox" + count++;
        div.onclick = function() {
            alert(this.id);
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
    };
    return addBox;
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery:

Bind the function to the event:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input#addButton', addBox);
```

The function:

```
function addBox() { 
var newId=$('div.clrBox').length + 1;
var $newBox=$('<div id="'+ newId +'"></div>')
    .addClass("clrBox")
)

$('body').append($newBox);
}
```

Comment: Poster has already indicated in comments that they cannot use jQuery.

Comment: Oops! I only saw his reply after posting this answer.